# Colocando uma hora inicial no Input date

Tags: javascript, html, html5, ionic, typescript

Boa tarde, teria como iniciar o campo date do input com a hora já preenchida ? no caso queria que inciasse com 23:59 e o campo de data por iniciar normal mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: Pelo que consta na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#Local_date_and_time_strings), o valor de um campo `datetime-local` deve ter sempre a data e hora, então ou vc seta tudo (como na resposta do @hugocsl abaixo) ou deixa todos os campos vazios. Não parece haver um jeito de preencher parcialmente (somente a data ou somente a hora). Se é isso que deseja, o jeito é ter dois campos separados (um para data, outro para a hora)

Comment: Israel, coloque o código na pergunta. Talvez vendo o código seja mais fácil de ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim aqui tem um exemplo, e veja a documentação da Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

```html
<input type="datetime-local" value="2019-04-26T23:59">
```

Link complementar com mais informações de formatos possível: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Suporte dos browsers**

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já tentei dessa forma aqui e não vai, pode ser pq estou fazendo no ionic ?

Comment: @IsraelGomes Pode sim, pq esse formato não é totalmente crossbrowser, no IE por exemplo não funciona, nos browsers mobile a referencia que tenho é a que editei na resposta com o link. Tb não sei dizer se é algum problema de compilação ou algo do tipo no Ionic.... só pesquisando pra saber

Comment: @IsraelGomes tente colocar a data som o `T` nesse formato para ver se passa `1986-01-28 11:38:00.010`

Comment: Não passa, deve ser algo do ionic mesmo

Comment: Hugo, e se eu quisesse começar com a data atual e deixar uma hora padrão, teria como ?

Comment: @IsraelGomes cara acredito que seja poosível sim, mas vc teria que usar algum script para pegar a data do dispositivo e colocar dentro do value do input, sendo que o horario vai ser fixo, seria algo como value=" {{dia}}+'T23:59' " tipo isso ai. Só que eu nao manjo nada de JS, mas se vc fizer uma nova pergunta com o código e perguntando como coloca só a parte inicial com a data do dia alguém vai saber te ajudar, na verdade talvez seja até duplicada rss, da uma pesquisada no site, se nao achar abre uma nova pergunta ;)

Comment: Hugo, valeu cara, decidi colocar a hora separada da data, assim caso o usuário não digite nada a hora inicia com 23:59, caso ele digite ela assume o valor digitado, Obrigado pela ajuda. Abraço!

Comment: @IsraelGomes é uma opçao valida tb, nao impacta muito o usuário e vc tem um controle melhor dos campos. Boa sorte com o projeto []'s